# Test autocomplete with Selenium webdriver

Tags: java, selenium, autocomplete, webdriver

I have a text box in which when I type one letter say 's' , it displays a list of results ( like google search) .

I am using latest selenium webdriver with java.

I have tried

```
sendKeys("s"),

JavascriptLibrary jsLib = new JavascriptLibrary();

jsLib.callEmbeddedSelenium(driver, "doFireEvent", driver.findElement(By.id("assetTitle")), "onkeyup");

    jsLib.callEmbeddedSelenium(driver, "doFireEvent", driver.findElement(By.id("assetTitle")), "onblur");

    jsLib.callEmbeddedSelenium(driver, "doFireEvent", driver.findElement(By.id("assetTitle")), "onclick");

    jsLib.callEmbeddedSelenium(driver, "doFireEvent", driver.findElement(By.id("assetTitle")), "onmouseup");


driver.findElement(By.id("assetTitle")).sendKeys(Keys.ENTER);
```

None of these work even after adding wait after each of the steps.

Any suggestions?

Thanks.

Update :-

```
WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver();
    driver.get("http://www.google.com");
    WebElement query = driver.findElement(By.name("q"));
    query.sendKeys("s");
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//table[@class='gssb_m']/tbody/tr/td/div/table/tbody/tr/td/span")).click();
    driver.findElement(By.name("btnG")).click();
```

Update 2 : -

```
WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver();
    driver.get("http://www.kayak.com/");
    WebElement query = driver.findElement(By.name("destination"));
    query.sendKeys("s");
```

Update 3 :-
       I tried with Selenium 1 and the fireevent method works by passing parameter as 'keydown'.  This should be a temporary workaround for now.

```
WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver();
    driver.get("http://www.kayak.com/");
    DefaultSelenium sel = new WebDriverBackedSelenium(driver,"http://www.kayak.com/");

    sel.type("//input[@id='destination']", "s");
    sel.fireEvent("//input[@id='destination']", "keydown");
```

Comment: Can you update your question with an example code that works with the Google search field?

Comment: I have added the sample google search code. Although the last step is not required as Google automatically brings the search results. But if you try for kayak.com then similar code will not work for searching airports.

Comment: Kayak sample added. By sending key 's', we should see airports starting with letter S.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should be a temporary workaround for now.

```
WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver();
    driver.get("http://www.kayak.com/");
    DefaultSelenium sel = new WebDriverBackedSelenium(driver,"http://www.kayak.com/");

    sel.type("//input[@id='destination']", "s");
    sel.fireEvent("//input[@id='destination']", "keydown");
```

Answer (score 3):

I found a workaround about this. My problem was:

1. Selenium inputted 'Mandaluyong' to an auto-suggest location field
2. The auto-suggest field appears together with the matched option
3. Then selenium left the auto-suggest drop-down open not selecting the matched option.

What I did was:

```
        driver.findElement(By.name("fromLocation")).sendKeys("Mandaluyong");
        driver.findElement(By.name("fromLocation")).sendKeys(Keys.TAB);
```

This is because on a manual test, when I try to press TAB key, two things were done by the system:

1. Picks the matched option from the auto-suggest drop-down
2. Closes the auto-suggest drop-down

Answer (score 1):

I believe you are testing auto-suggest here (not auto-complete)

Steps I follow -

1. Enter something in the input field
2. Click on the suggestion you want to choose. (You can find the xpath using some tools like Firebug with Firepath, Chrome, etc.)
3. Verify the text in the input field is same as expected.