# Iterator in selenium webdriver

Tags: selenium

I need to collect all the options from auto drop-down when I type "test" in Google search.

After collecting, I need to print it to console.

Note: Don't hit **ENTER** Button

Comment: The following link may be helpful to you. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9202061/test-autocomplete-with-selenium-webdriver

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like home work =)
It should be something like this:

```
    WebElement searchField = driver.findElement(By.name("q"));
    searchField.sendKeys("test");
    List<WebElement> resultList = driver.findElements(By.xpath("//div[@class='gsq_a']/table/tbody/tr/td/span"));
    for (WebElement resultItem : resultList){
        System.out.println(resultItem.getText());
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this code:

```
WebElement searchField = driver.findElement(By.name("q"));

searchField.sendKeys("test");

Thread.sleep(2000);

List <WebElement> rows = driver.findElements(By.cssSelector("table[class='gssb_m'] > tbody > tr "));

for (WebElement resultItem : rows){

   System.out.println(resultItem.findElement(By.cssSelector("td > div > table > tbody > tr > td:nth-of-type(1)")).getText());

}
```