# How to click an option in an auto-suggest input textfield? Selenium WebDriver

Tags: java, selenium

I am running a test using Selenium WebDriver

I have an issue with an input textfield *("Select Source: By Name:")*.
When I enter a String "ABC Premium News (Australia)" in the textfield, an option would show up. Then I need to click (or select) it. I tried ALL methods w/ fireEvent...no use.

The following is the source code:

```
driver.get("http://www..."); 
driver.switchTo().frame("mainFrame");
WebElement sourceTitle = driver.findElement(By.name("sourceTitle"));
sourceTitle.sendKeys("ABC Premium News (Australia)"); 
//Now a "combobox-like" option "ABC Premium News (Australia)" shows up...how do I click it?

// I tried fireEvent...it did not help. The following is one of my trials that does not work:
DefaultSelenium sel = new WebDriverBackedSelenium(driver,"http://www....");
sel.type("//input[@id='destination']", "ABC Premium News (Australia)");
sel.fireEvent("//input[@id='destination']", "keydown");
// In addition to keydown, I tried: onclick, onfocus, onblur...
```

Comment: take a look here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9202061/test-autocomplete-with-selenium-webdriver

Comment: I am sorry @Amine Hajyoussef. I tried again, it appears that this method helps only to input the values into the textfiled, however, it DOES NOT help to choose the "combo box - like" option. ANYBODY, please, run the above code lines OR visit the website to check out the textfield.

Comment: can you show us the html and a screenshot?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I know this is not the best one could come up with but still it can be used as temporary workaround.

```
WebElement sourceTitle = driver.findElement(By.name("sourceTitle"));

WebElement small = driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("li#nameExampleSection label + small"));

sourceTitle.sendKeys("ABC Premium News (Australia)"); 

Thread.sleep(5000);

Actions actions = new Actions(driver);

actions.click(small).perform();
```